# why the keys j k can't move down and up in my vim for windows?

Tags: vim

In my vim for windows ,<kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> keys can move left and right,but the keys <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> can't move down and up, what is wrong with my configuration file or some other thing?

Comment: How are we supposed to know if you won't tell us more about your configuration? For a start, are there any mappings?! What does `:map j` tell you?

Comment: you have CAPS LOCK on?

Comment: i fount that the answer is that i don't press enter ,so the line is still one line but in the screen they are more lines.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments you discovered that j/k were not moving on screen lines, because you only actually had a single line of text.

So here are some suggestions to help, use together or independently:

1. Use gj and gk to move around. Map these to keys if you wish, even remapping j/k if you prefer.
2. Use the 'showbreak' option, to visually see when a line is a real line and when it is just part of a wrapped line.
3. Use 'formatoptions' and 'textwidth' options to insert line breaks automatically instead of using 'wrap' like you do now.